# How do I set up an IPv6 tunnel in Fedora?

Tags: networking, fedora, ipv6

I have been experimenting with IPv6. Hurricane Electric through their http://tunnelbroker.net service offer a free IPv6 tunnel. I would like to be able to use this reliably on my Fedora 14 desktop workstation. I've tried a number of different recipes on the web to get this set up but none seem to fit a straightforward workstation install.

I currently use the older static network set up (through /etc/init.d/network) rather than NetworkManager on a wired Ethernet network.

Comment: There is an answer in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/351358/241396

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing was similar to Scott's answer but had a few extra steps.

Create file /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-he-ipv6 with:

```
DEVICE=he-ipv6
TYPE=sit
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes                         # set to "no" if you prefer to start the tunnel manually
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6TUNNELIPV4=216.66.80.26        # Server IPv4 address (this the HE London tunnel server)
IPV6ADDR=2001:xxx:xxxx:xxx::x/64   # Client IPv6 address
```

Also ensure that /etc/sysconfig/network contains:

```
NETWORKING_IPV6=yes
IPV6_DEFAULTDEV=he-ipv6
```

The tunnel comes up quickly every time and survived upgrades to F15 and F16.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this isn't exactly the OS you are using, but for CentOS 5.5, I just created /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-sit1:

```
BOOTPROTO="none"
DEVICE="sit1"
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6TUNNELIPV4=xx.xx.xx.xx
IPV6TUNNELIPV4LOCAL=yy.yy.yy.yy
IPV6ADDR="2001:xxx:x:xxx::x/64"
ONBOOT=yes
```

For the remote tunnel endpoint (xx.xx.xx.xx), it can be found on the tunnelbroker.net site , and the local one (yy.yy.yy.yy) is just my internal (behind NAT) IPv4 address.

The tunnel does seem to take some time to come up.  Still looking into that, actually.